# Example of a set that is neither open nor closed in given metric space $M$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I gave this example:

$a\in M$, take the closed ball $B[a,r]=\{x\in M | d(a,x)\leq r\}$, take an element $x$ such that $d(a,x)=r$ and do $S=B[a,r]-\{x\}$. It's easy to prove that this set is neither closed nor open.

My problem with this is that i don't know if it's guaranteed that a point $x$ such as the one i choose will exist, because if you put

$$d(a,b)=\begin{cases}
      0 & \text{if }a\neq b\\
      1 & \text{if } a=b
    \end{cases} $$

and choose $0<r<1$, than this $x$ will not exist, and if you put $r\geq1$ then $B[a,r]=M$ and for any $x$, we have that $M-\{x\}$ still is an open set.

Comment: Your fear is correct. Under the metric you've defined, every set will be both closed and open in the induced topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, if for instance $M$ is finite and $d$ is the metric you defined, then the topology is discrete and hence every subset of $M$ is clopen (= closed and open).